# Передача return на уровень выше

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Столкнулся с проблемой: с помощью return получается только передать промис в следующий then, а не вернуть его из функции. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Код приложил ниже

```js
const App = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/getprops')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            // Отсюда вернуть значение из функции App, а не передать его в следующую цепочку then
    })
};
```

update: Исправил, вышло это:

```js
const App = () => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(undefined)
    const [smth, setSmth] = useState(undefined)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3001/getprops')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(setSmth)
            .catch(setError)
    }, [])

    return (
            error ? <h3>Ошибка</h3>
                    : !smth ? <div></div>
                    :   <div className="App" id="App">
                            // мое приложение
                        </div>
    )

};
```

Comment: В тот момент когда вы исполняете код под комментарием, функция `App` уже завершилась. Так работают промисы: сперва завершается функция создавшая промис, затем выполняются блоки `then`. Так работает асинхронность. Если вы хотите вернуть осмысленный результат из App (не промис верхнего уровня, в какой-то результат из какого-то блока `then`, то вы требуете чтобы код был синхронным. Это противоречит асинхронной природе промисов, и иногда вообще невозможно. Меняйте архитектуру этого куска.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Уже исправил

Answer (score 1):

```
function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState()
  const [smth, setSmth] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/smth')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(res => setSmth(res))
      .catch(err => setError(err))
  }, [])

  return (
      error   ?   <h1>Ooops...</h1>
    : !smth   ?   <h1>Loading...</h1>
    :             <SomeOtherThing smth={smth} />
  )
}
```

Comment: А ещё можно через [Suspense](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/Suspense).

Answer (score 0):

Как то так должно выглядеть

```
const App = () => {
  const [jsxEl, setJsx] = useState(null);

  const dataRequest = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/getprops')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        // Придумываем jsx
        setJsx(<div>{res.text}</div>)
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dataRequest();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {jsxEl}
    </>
  )
}
```

В таком случае, можно будет повторно, при необходимости вызывать функцию запроса данных

Comment: Это компонент реакта, а они не могут быть асинхронными. Так же, таким образом из функции возвращается промис

Comment: @havaka окей. Как тогда **bulbProps** используется? Для чего?

Comment: извиняюсь, забыл объявление переменной удалить. Мне просто нужно вернуть jsx документ с содержанием, зависящим от ответа fetch

Comment: @havaka Fetch вызывается по событию или только в момент первого рендера?

Comment: только по первому рендеру

Comment: Можно без фрагмента.